# how to run sql queries on mat file

Tags: sql, matlab

I have a file xyz.mat in Matlab that contains a RetailWeek table. I would like to run sql queries on RetailWeek but is there any way to do this in Matlab?

I know I can do this in R using the sqldf package but I need to do this in Matlab.

Comment: http://au.mathworks.com/help/database/run-sql-query.html

Comment: What kind of sql commands would you like to run? The first step should be to format your data as a 'matlab table' http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html, after that varfun and rowfun are your friends and can be used to emulate GROUP BYs, SELECTs can be emulated using standard matlab booleans